# How many global variables a smart contract or dapp for Algorand can have?

Tags: algorand

Hey guys i was wondering how many global variable can i have for a algorand smart contract or dapp?

I'm currently using pyteal to write a smart contact for my dapp.

Answer (score 4):

Smart contracts on Algorand can currently have:

- 64 global variables (key/values)
- 16 local variables (key/values) per account that opt-in

The page https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-details/parameter_tables/#smart-contract-constraints indicates the current parameters.

You need to specify at time of creation how many global and local variables and their types.